# Typehint tuple of ints gives IDE warning. List of ints does not. Why?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Why does the typehint `tuple[int]` behave differently from `list[int]`?

This gives me a visual warning:

```
def func_with_tuple(x: tuple[int]):
    pass
    
    
func_with_tuple((1, 2, 3))

#                  ^
# warning _________|
```

> Expected type 'tuple[int]', got 'tuple[int, int, int]' instead

while this does not:

```
def func_with_list(x: list[int]):
        pass
    
    
func_with_list([1, 2, 3])
```

How should I typehint a `tuple` of `ints` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, looking at [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-typing-module) where the Python type annotation system was defined, it states:

> `Tuple`, used by listing the element types, for example `Tuple[int, int, str]`. The empty tuple can be typed as `Tuple[()]`.
> Arbitrary-length homogeneous tuples can be expressed using one type
> and ellipsis, for example `Tuple[int, ...]`. (The `...` here are part
> of the syntax, a literal ellipsis.)

Note, that PEP uses `typing.Tuple`, which is currently [deprecated in favor of `tuple`, but it still documents this same thing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple).
So,

```
tuple[int]
```

Means *a length 1 tuple with an `int`.

`tuple` objects and `list` objects are used differently. A list should be thought of as an arbitrary-sized, homogenous sequence. `tuple` objects are more like record types, fixed-size, with possibly heterogenous types. Hence, their type annotation has different semantics.

So you either want:

```
tuple[int, ...]
```

Or

```
tuple[int, int, int]
```